# What this string of signs in jpql means?

Tags: java, jpql

```
@Query("Select u.email from User u where u.email= ?#{[0]}")
Optional<String> getEmail(String email);
```

my question is, what this `?#{[0]}` means, I know the query should return email but what this string of signs mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is SpEL support in jpql.
**?#{[0]}** means an indexed access to the method parameters instead of using a named access. So it represents the email parameter that is passed to your getEmail method: the parameter with index 0 in other words your first parameter if your method signature was for example

Optional getServiceEmail(String email, int officeId);

You could access the second parameter using **?#{[1]}** with the following

```
@Query("Select u.email from User u where u.email= ?#{[0]} and u.officeId=?#{[1]} ")
Optional<String> getServiceEmail(String email, int officeId);
```

. Another way to obtain the same result would be to use a named acces via the @Param method

```
@Query("Select u.email from User u where u.email= :#{#email}")
Optional<String> getEmail(@Param("email") String email);
```

So you can use one or the other approach

Comment: Isn't it the same as `@Query("Select u.email from User u where u.email= ?0")` and `@Query("Select u.email from User u where u.email= :email)`?

Comment: @Dimasan, yes it gives the same result. There are often many ways to 'skin' the code cat :)